# how to add Cross Origin Resource Sharing in my java fie

Tags: java, restful-authentication

I have written this it's not correct

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
                .allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write component class for CORS origin filter

```
 @Component
public class CorsFilterConfiguration implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type, authToken"); //TODO: Fix 'token' to 'OAuth' / 'SAML' header.
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am not implementing servlet .I am using a main function where i am producing restful web-services. Is there any way to make it without using servelt filters ??

Comment: You can set these in your response also
return Response.ok()
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With").build();

Comment: This is the my code . how would i do this please help

Comment: public static void main(String[] args){HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();String loginURL =;
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
{
System.out.println("Error authenticating to Force.com: "+statusCode);
}

String getResult = null;

getResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

ioException.printStackTrace();
}

httpPost.releaseConnection();
}

Comment: yes . i was producing restful webservices so that at clintside an angular js application can consume it